# Parsing a site in python

Tags: python, ajax, parsing, encryption, python-requests

There is a site https://www.flashscore.ru/. I need to parse the 'Odds' category from there. But I do not know how to do this, the site has a loading using ajax. But when I look at this ajax I can’t find the very request that I need, all requests are encrypted as well. Tell me how to decrypt requests or where it can be read. I must say right away that I can’t open the browser, because the script will work on the server (without selenium type libraries). If there is a ready-made solution, I will be very happy

Comment: If you can't run e.g. puppeteer and scrape from that, you'll have to reverse-engineer the script that loads data from the encrypted/obfuscated response. A good starting point is to turn on your browser's debugger's "Break on external requests" feature and see what happens to the data the script retrieves.

Comment: how to encrypt the answer?  is there an option without viewing js code?